# ActionViolation when using LockBits

Tags: c#, .net, .net-core, gdi+, lockbits

I am trying to get the pixels a bit faster than one could when using `.GetPixel()` but I have found myself that it throws an exception with a 0,0 index with the right `LockImageMode`.

Exception

> Attempted to read or write protected memory. This is often an indication that other memory is corrupt.

````cs
public async Task<IList<Color>> GetColorStream( )
    {
        (_Width, _Height, PixelFormat pixelFormat) = await GetDimensions(_Path);
        List<Color> pixels = new();
        if (pixelFormat is not PixelFormat.Format32bppRgb or not PixelFormat.Format24bppRgb or not PixelFormat.Format32bppRgb)
            throw new InvalidOperationException("Cant operate with ess than 24bpps");

         _Data = await GetBitmapData(_Width, _Height, pixelFormat, ImageLockMode.ReadWrite);

        if(pixelFormat is PixelFormat.Format24bppRgb or PixelFormat.Format32bppRgb)
        {
            for (int i = 0; i < _Width; i++)
                for (int j = 0; j < _Height; j++)
                {
                    int stride = i * _Data.Stride / 3 + j;
                    (byte R, byte G, byte B, byte A) = (Marshal.ReadByte(_Data.Scan0, stride), Marshal.ReadByte(_Data.Scan0, stride + 1),
                                                      Marshal.ReadByte(_Data.Scan0, stride + 2), 0);
                    pixels.Add(new Color(R, G, B, A));
                }
        }
        else if(pixelFormat == PixelFormat.Format32bppArgb )
        {
            for (int i = 0; i < _Width; i++)
                for (int j = 0; j < _Height; j++)
                {
                    int stride = i * _Data.Stride / 4 + j;
                    (byte R, byte G, byte B, byte A) = (Marshal.ReadByte(_Data.Scan0, stride), Marshal.ReadByte(_Data.Scan0, stride + 1),
                                                      Marshal.ReadByte(_Data.Scan0, stride + 2), Marshal.ReadByte(_Data.Scan0, stride + 3));
                    pixels.Add(new Color(R, G, B, A));
                }
        }
        image.UnlockBits(_Data);
        image = null;
        return pixels;
    }```
````

Comment: The offset of the first of the three (four) bytes to read in that loop would be `_Data.Stride * j + i * 3` (`_Data.Stride * j + i * 4` respectively). If you want speed improvements, better read in bulk, not in bytes. And read by lines, not by columns, so that the memory access is sequential rather than all over the place.

Comment: The code is not handling Format32bppRgb correctly, stride is then a multiple of 4.  The simple solution is to handle only a single format, 32bppArgb, passing that to GetBitmapData().  You also greatly prefer Marshal.ReadInt32() to speed up the code, Color.FromArgb() to convert the int to Color.

Comment: @HansPassant Stride is always a multiple of four...

Comment: His stride variable, not the bitmap's stride.

Comment: @GSerg is it always true for 24bpp? so you are telling me to copy the whole in array rather iterating through the BitmapData?

Comment: @HansPassant His `int stride` is the current offset relative to `Scan0` to read the next 3 (4) bytes from. A stride cannot be different for each read operation.

Comment: @PontiacGTX Is what true? How the offset is calculated from Scan0 and Stride, by multiplying Stride to the number of passed lines (not columns)? Yes, that is true for all bpp. It is also true for all bpp that Stride is divisible by 4.

Comment: @GSerg I assumed that the 24bpp were only 3 channels only with 8 bytes each.

Comment: @GSerg it doesnt work with the default value PixelFormat.Format24bppRgb but if I sent  PixelFormat.Format32bppArgb then lockbits BitmapData works.... what could be the issue?

Comment: Because you are trying to divide the strive by 3? 24bpp is three channels only with 8 bytes each. That does not mean the stride is divisible by 3. The stride is always divisible by four. Sometimes by 3 as well, but only as a coincidence. You are not supposed to divide it in the first place. See the first comment.

Comment: @GSerg I have updated my code and dividing by 3 it doesnt crash but PixelFormat should be 32bits otherwise LockBits wont work

Comment: it's much more efficient to just increase your read offset by `stride` on every `y` iteration, and copy that into a separate variable which you increase by the amount of bytes (3 or 4) on every `x` iteration. Then you don't need to do multiplications in every single loop.

Comment: @Nyerguds should I divide oe get the mod for the most suitable ```stride```value in this loop I supose?

Comment: Most suitable stride? There is only one stride, and it's `_Data.Stride`. You can't _choose_ the stride.

Comment: @Nyerguds but I mean the most suitable divider per pixelcount  as you say reading in batch is much faster

Comment: There is no "divider". You increase your x per block of bytes corresponding to the pixel size, but every y-step, you just take the previous line's start and add the stride to get the next line's start.